# First appearance of Euclidean algorithm with Euclidean divisions

Tags: nt.number-theory, ho.history-overview

When was first described the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) using Euclidean divisions?

In Euclid's original presentation¹ in his *Elements*, each step consists in repeated subtractions, while the *modern* presentations of course use Euclidean division. Whence my question, when did this modern version first appeared?

Knuth [1] and Shallit [2] present the interesting history of the first complexity analyses of the modern version of the algorithm, but do not provide an answer to my question.

---

[1] D. E. Knuth, *The Art of Computer Programming*, volume 2: *Seminumerical Algorithms*, 3rd ed. Addison-Wesley Professional, 1997.

[2] J. Shallit, *Origins of the analysis of the Euclidean algorithm*, Historia Mathematica, vol. 21, no. 4, pp. 401–419, Nov. 1994.

¹ Though as mentioned by many authors, the algorithm was probably known before Euclid.

Comment: Would you please explain the difference between repeated subtraction and division with remainder when it comes to $a-bq=r$?

Comment: Repeated subtraction is only one inefficient algorithm for division with remainder. And modern descriptions of the Euclidean algorithm directly describe one step as "compute the remainder" rather than "repeatedly subtract the smaller from the larger". I wonder when this switch occurred.

Comment: The Euclidean algorithm does not say anything about how to perform the calculation. How do *you* compute the remainder of $22$ when divided by $7$?

Comment: That's almost my point: The modern presentation of the Euclidean algorithm does not say anything about how to perform division, while the original one tells the computer to repeatedly perform subtractions. (And for "my" method if I am doing mental calculation: The standard long division algorithm, with some heuristics to find the digits of the quotient. Never repeated subtractions!)

Comment: Euclid could only obtain the remainder using repeated subtraction since the elements do not deal with fractions (let alone decimal or sexagesimal digits). Euclid does not demand that you compute remainders this way; for large numbers, he probably would have told you to use an abacus. The divisions in Aristarch and Archimedes most certainly were not made using repeated subtractions.